# Unable to edit a comment as on save it gives two different pop-ups

Tags: support, editing, comments

I am trying to re-word my comment as it has gone very lengthy but when I do so it gives two different pop-up's every time I try to save.

At first it gives a pop-up saying that "Comment's may be edited only every 5 minutes" .At 11:11 i tried to edit that comment 
[image]
On 11:16 it's 5 mins so I re-try to save but when I am click on save it gave another pop-up You may only edit a Comment every 5 seconds.

When i re-try it after 10 seconds it gave me the first pop-up "Comment's may be edited only every 5 minutes"

Answer (score 4):

It does not say *every* five minutes.  After five minutes have passed since you posted it, you cannot edit anymore.

Comment: Then what about the 5 seconds

Comment: @user285oo6 I am going to guess that you clicked save twice after the 5 minutes has expired. Like you double clicked on "save edits". This in turn tried to save the edit twice within the 5 second threshold.

Comment: Isn't it that error message should be Comments may be edited only within 5 minutes and not for 5 minutes.

Comment: For the 5 secs message i tried to do as you said and it happened exactly but I don't understand when we are not supposed to edit after 5 mins then giving this 5 seconds alert is also wrong as you mentioned that 5 min threshold has expired

Comment: "within 5 minutes" and "for 5 minutes", to me, means the same thing. within 5 minutes of creating it. For 5 minutes after creating it.